# Check for value in collection

Tags: java, collections

I'm trying to check a collection for a particular value

i.e. I want to check the collection of players for a positionType = attacker. It does not matter how man references, as long as there is at least one.

Every attempt so far has failed me.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public Player findFirstAttacker(Collection<Player> players) {
  for (Player p : players) {
    if (p.getPositionType() == Player.POSITION_ATTACKER) {
      return p;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: +1: This is likely closer to what damien wants than my answer.  It could also be converted to a boolean test (to me, this is what "check" implies) by returning `true` and `false` instead of `p` and `null` respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try the [Collection.contains()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method?

If so, and it was returning the wrong answer, check that the implementations of `equals()` and `hashCode()` on the class of the player are appropriate.  These methods will (probably) be used to check whether the collection contents are equal to the object you pass in, so if they are left as the default implementations inherited from `Object` you may not get the behaviour you expect.

Answer (score 2):

[guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has:

```
boolean hasAttackers = Iterables.any(list, new Predicate<Player>() {
    public boolean apply(Player player) {
        return player.getPosition().equals(PositionType.ATTACKER);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the better answer as it works if position is a String (instead of a primitive or enum).

Answer (score 0):

```
public Player getFirstAttacker(Collection<Player> playerCollection) {

 for (Player player : playerCollection) {
   if (player.getPosition() == Position.attacker) {
     return player;
   }
 }

 return null;
}
```